# Excel VBA Type Mismatch Error Using Evaluate with Variants

Tags: vba, excel

I'm experiencing a type mismatch error in VBA excel with the following code:

```
M(i, GPARAM(1)) = Evaluate(Func & "(" & EvalVect & "," & GPARAM & ")")
```

Where Func is a string containing the name of a function and EvalVect & GPARAM are both variants.

If I hardcode the expression, explicity specifying the function name, it runs without issue, so the problem is due to my understanding of the evaluate function not the UDF.

```
M(i, GPARAM(1)) = Func1(EvalVect, GPARAM)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `Evaluate` works as if you entered the formula string into a cell. Does your formula string work in a cell?

Comment: Have you noticed that in the `Type mismatch` your function is named `Func` while in the working example is named `Func1`?

Comment: If it is working as you say then you may just be missing a '1' from the expression to give: Evaluate(Func1 & "(" & EvalVect & ", " & GPARAM & ")")

Comment: My goal is to use an arbitrary function, as defined by `Func = Worksheets("Inputs").Cells(4, 2).Value`, which is Func1. As for if it works in a cell, the variants EvalVect and GPARAM are populated in VBA and don't exist in the spreadsheet so I'm not sure how to test in a cell.  Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to evaluate lines of VBA code rather than a usable worksheet formula string, `Evaluate` won't work, but you could just put the functions into a class module and use `CallByName`.

Comment: I'm attempting to modify the following to incorporate variants vs single values: `f0 = Evaluate(Func & "(" & Str(x0) & ")")`. This expression works.

Comment: Again, unless you can type: `=Func1(EvalVect, GPARAM)` in a cell and have it calculate (which it appears it won't), you can't use `Evaluate` for this.

Comment: @Rory , that sounds like it's problem. I suppose I could store the two arrays within a worksheet and reference them as A1:A10 but I would prefer all the work happens without using the worksheets. I will try out `CallByName`. Thanks

Comment: Depending on how you populated the arrays, you might be able to use something like this: `M(i, GPARAM(1)) = Evaluate(Func & "({" & Join(EvalVect, ",") & "},{" & Join(GPARAM, ",") & "})")`

Answer (score 1):

you're `GPARAM` is an array and you're trying to add it to a string - note that you need to give it's index.

```
Evaluate(Func & "(" & EvalVect & "," & GPARAM(1) & ")")
```